How to add and update record based on condition?
I want to insert new record when Id = 0 and update when Id != 0, but my problem is l don't know to rewrite the if/else condition to execute this in my code. Below is what l had tried.
service.ts
 post(user: any){
  console.log(user);
  return this.http.post<any>(this.APIUrl,user);
 }

 put(user: any){
  console.log(user);
  return this.http.put<any>(this.APIUrl,user);
 } 

component.ts
 public orderForm = new FormGroup({
  Id: new FormControl(0),
  Name: new FormControl(null),
  Type: new FormControl(null),
 });

 onSubmit(orderForm: FormGroup) {
  this.submitted = true;
  if(this.orderForm.valid){
   if(this.service.post(this.orderForm.Id == 0)) //this is where the error is
     this.insert();
   else
     this.update();
   }    
 }

 insert(){
  this.service.post(this.orderForm.value).subscribe((result) =>{
   console.log(result);
   this.orderForm.reset();
   this.toastr.success('Inserted Successfully')
  });
 }

 update(){
  this.service.put(this.orderForm.value).subscribe((result) =>{
   console.log(result);
   this.orderForm.reset();
   this.toastr.info('Updated Successfully')
  });
 }


Shouldn't that just be if(orderForm.Id == 0)? Why are you trying to POST before knowing whether or not it should be a POST?!

I hope you check the ID, from  the form (orderForm), then the code will be like so.
Make sure you patchValue the form ID into the Id form control, which is not necessary. It's better you check the data object that you use to patchValue the values into the form.
Then the code will be (this.dataObject.Id || 0) === 0:
public orderForm = new FormGroup({
  Id: new FormControl(0),
  Name: new FormControl(null),
  Type: new FormControl(null),
 });

 onSubmit(orderForm: FormGroup) {
  this.submitted = true;
  if(this.orderForm.valid){
   const isPost = (this.orderForm.value?.Id || 0) === 0;
   const api$ = isPost ? this.service.post(this.orderForm.value) : this.service.put(this.orderForm.value);
   api$.subscribe({
       next: (response: any) => {
           // this get called when action is successful
           this.toast.success(isPost ? 'Create Successful' : 'Update Successful');
       },
       error: () => {
           // this get called when action has failed!
           this.toast.error(isPost ? 'Create Failed' : 'Update Failed');
       }
   });
 }


thank you for the solution. As you can see there is toast method in my code so, I am confused on how to apply toasts for record inserted(success) and record updated (info) in your code.

I had tried your code, it only inserting new record but it's not updating any existing one

@Milie24 check why the if condition needs to be configured properly, there is not enough data to fix fully, just check why the if condition is falling

I am getting this error ' : ' expected from this line of code const isPost = this.orderForm.value?.Id === 0; When l remove the ' ? ' the error goes away. Is the ' ? ' neccessary?

@Milie24 sorry plz try (this.orderForm.value?.Id || 0) === 0 when you do put call, check if id has a value! that is the first step to solve the issue!

both your first and last modifications work fine. There was a mistake at my end. Thank you for the solution.
